# Save score in a game with NSUserdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've made this little app "How many fingers" where the user has to guess how many fingers the computer is holding behind it's back. Now I want it to be able to save the users score with NSUserdefaults, but it's not working. Here is how my code looks right now:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  How many Fingers?
//
//  Created by Kevin Nguyen on 02.05.15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Kevin Nguyen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var userGuess: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var userScore: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var userTotal: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var result: UILabel!
    var score:Int = 0
    var totalGames:Int = 0

    @IBAction func resetScore(sender: AnyObject) {
        score = 0
        userScore.text = "0"
    }


    @IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
        var userGuessInt = userGuess.text.toInt()
        var fingers = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
        if userGuessInt <= 5 {
            if userGuessInt == fingers {
                result.text = "Great! You were right!"
                score++
                totalGames++
                userScore.text = "\(score)"
                userTotal.text = "\(totalGames)"
                println("User score is \(score); total games is \(totalGames)")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "svScore")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(totalGames, forKey: "svTotalGames")
            } else {
                result.text = "Try Again!"
                println("User score is \(score); total games is \(totalGames)")
                totalGames++
                userTotal.text = "\(totalGames)"
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(score, forKey: "svScore")
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(totalGames, forKey: "svTotalGames")
            }

        } else{
            result.text = "Enter a number from 0 up to 5!"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        if score != 0 {
            var score:Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svScore")! as! Int
            userScore.text = "\(score)"
        }
        if totalGames != 0 {
            var totalGames:Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svTotalGames")! as! Int
            userTotal.text = "\(totalGames)"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not suggest you using NSUserDefault. Use model/singelton method instead NSUSerDefault because of security issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your application starts the `score` in `viewDidLoad` is always `0`. So you'll never read the saved data (because of your `if` condition). You should also check it there is data stored before you try to use it.

Change it like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svScore") != nil) {
        score = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svScore")! as! Int
    }
    if score != 0 {
        userScore.text = "\(score)"
    }

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svTotalGames") != nil) {
         totalGames = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("svTotalGames")! as! Int
    }
    if totalGames != 0 {
        userTotal.text = "\(totalGames)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the code, and at first I actually thought that it worked. When I open the app and for example have a score of 3 and total games of 15 from the last time I opened the app, and then if I start guessing again it just resets the total games to 0 and the score gets rested too, but not before I guess one right. Then the two numbers go up normally while I play the game. What can be done ?

Comment: @kevini15 I made a small mistake using local and global variables. I removed two lines from the code in my answer. Please try again with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
//To Save Highscore
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(highScore, forKey: "highscore")
//To Call For Highscore
var highScore:Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("highscore")
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Answer (score 0):

You could create a HighscoreSaver-util class like that:

```
class HighscoreSaver {
    private let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    private let highscoreKey = "highscore-saver-key-item"
    private var highscore:Int = 0

    private func updateHighscore(score:Int){
        highscore += score
        if defaults.integerForKey(highscoreKey) < highscore{
            defaults.setInteger(highscore, forKey: highscoreKey)
        }
    }

    func add(score scoreToAdd:Int){
        updateHighscore(scoreToAdd)
    }

    func reset(){
        defaults.removeObjectForKey(highscoreKey)
    }

    func currentHighscore() -> Int{
        return highscore
    }
}
```

The usage would be like that:

```
var high = HighscoreSaver()

//Adds scorevalue to current score
high.add(score: yourScoreToAddToCurrent)

//Resets the score to 0
high.reset()

//Gets current score
high.currentHighscore()
```